# automatically zoom map to maximum extent of wms layer

Tags: wms, openlayers-2

I try to automatically zoom map to maximum extent of layer after adding
layer to map.
I tried to code like this.

```
var layer = OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(.......);

map.addLayer(layer);

map.zoomToExtent(layer.getDataExtent());
```

But it doesnt' work. I also changed like this

```
map.zoomToExtent(layer.getMaxExtent());
```

It still doesn't work. What can I do to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

getDataExtent() does not work with a WMS layer, there is more info in the answer given here: [How to get layer extent in OpenLayers or zoom to WMS layer extent?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129511/how-to-get-layer-extent-in-open-layers-or-zoom-to-wms-layer-extent)

Comment: Thanks you, But those answers doesn't solve my problem

Comment: The linked answer has a suggestion:
"You can call the GetCapabilities request on the WMS endpoint. This gives you an XML response, which can be parsed to read the bbox of the appropriate Layer"